# Checking if a list of tuples is a subset of another

Tags: python, list, set

Firstly, note that I have gone through the other list-subset questions and they are not related to my problem here.

I have two lists

```
>>> l1 = [[(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked')]]
>>>
>>> l2 = [(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked'), (9, 8, 'CC', 'cc', -1, 'and', 'and'), (10, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'angry', 'angry')]
```

I'm trying to check if one is a subset of another.

But before that I checked out the results of subtracting one list from another and I got disappointing results -

```
>>> [word for word in l1 if word not in l2]
[[(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked')]]

>>> [word for word in l2 if word not in l1]
[(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked'), (9, 8, 'CC', 'cc', -1, 'and', 'and'), (10, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'angry', 'angry')]
```

Why am I getting identical lists as my results?
Does this have something to do with the fact that they are tuples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `l1` is a list of list of tuple (i.e. [[tuple]]), whereas `l2` is a list of tuple (i.e. [tuple]). If you change this the output from the list comprehensions are what you expect:

```
l1 = [(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked')]
l2 = [(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked'), (9, 8, 'CC', 'cc', -1, 'and', 'and'), (10, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'angry', 'angry')]
​
a = [word for word in l1 if word not in l2]
b = [word for word in l2 if word not in l1]
​
print a
print b

[]
[(9, 8, 'CC', 'cc', -1, 'and', 'and'), (10, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'angry', 'angry')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset),

```
l1 = [(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked')]
l2 = [(7, -1, 'VBD', 'null', -1, 'looked', 'looked'), (8, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'shocked', 'shocked'), (9, 8, 'CC', 'cc', -1, 'and', 'and'), (10, 7, 'JJ', 'xcomp', -1, 'angry', 'angry')]

>>> set(l1).issubset(l2)
True
```

Comment: `issubset` takes an arbitrary iterable object as its argument; you don't need to create a set first.

Comment: Are u sure by `set(l1)` you didn't get any sort of error message, like `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` ?

Comment: @IronFist, I did notice that `l1` in OP is a list of list of tuples. I supposed it is a slip of the pen. So, my answer assumes that `l1` is a list of tuples to line up with the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sets and the <= operator (is subset of).

```
>>> l1 = [2,4,6,8]
>>> l2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>> set(l1) <= set(l2)
True
```

Comment: I already tried that. I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`